# Recover deleted user Files from guest account

Tags: users

I had installed Gmail, and that had created a lot of users on the login screen. So I decided to delete them. But as I deleted them, I lost my user account. Now when I login there's only guest login option.

Hence I have to recover my files that were in the user account.I know `e2undel` but how can I do it (install and execute from the guest account) when I don't know the password of the root.

Comment: Boot from a liveCD and mount your harddrive, then you can pull off the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu don't have a root password. That said, you should try going for the "Recovery Mode" in the GRUB *"Advanced options"*, select *"Drop to root shell prompt"* then create your system user with `adduser`:

```
adduser user
```

Then reboot and login with your new user. Also, you should make sure your new user is member of the `admin` and `sudo` group.

```
adduser admin user
adduser sudo user
```

If during this commands the system complains about being on read-only or that files couldn't be written, the run this:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
```

Comment: Though its late but thanks for the help!! Saved me a lot of files!